# automount with autofs setup but not working

Tags: samba, automount, nfs

Again I am stuck with setting up auto-mounting with autofs. As i tried this a few times before I stayed with mounting manually when I needed access but i am fedup mounting manually so, here I go again trying to get this to work.

I have looked through a bunch of tutorials, as well as my old and similar question but I can't get it to work.

The most helpfull for me was:
https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-mount-nfs-filesystems-with-autofs-on-ubuntu-20-04/

When I mount manually is use the following, which works like a charm:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.100:/volume2/Files /mnt/nas
```

For the `autofs` setup I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install autofs
sudo nano /etc/auto.master
```

and added at the end and saved:

```
/nas   /etc/auto.nfs
```

```
sudo nano /etc/auto.nfs
```

added and saved:

```
/nas   -fstype=nfs4   192.168.1.100:/volume2/Files
```

then:

```
sudo service autofs reload
sudo service autofs status
```

output:

```
● autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on demand
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autofs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-04-03 17:41:34 CEST; 26min ago
       Docs: man:autofs(8)
    Process: 1426 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/automount $OPTIONS --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid (code>
    Process: 6599 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1434 (automount)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 37960)
     Memory: 2.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/autofs.service
             └─1434 /usr/sbin/automount --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid

apr 03 17:41:34 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Automounts filesystems on demand...
apr 03 17:41:34 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Automounts filesystems on demand.
apr 03 18:08:05 pop-os systemd[1]: Reloading Automounts filesystems on demand.
apr 03 18:08:05 pop-os systemd[1]: Reloaded Automounts filesystems on demand.
```

which seems a good output. Still when I open `/nas`, the shared nas folder is not mounted.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong would be very much appreciated.

ps:
I used `/nas` instead of `/mnt/nas` as that one was already "used" by the manual mount although not this boot session.I also tried `/mnt/nas` too as that folder is already existing anyways so. I also rebooted. All still to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble starting `autofs`.  Finally, I could solve it by just specifying a relative path instead of an absolute path in `auto.fs`.
So, your files should look something like

**auto.master**

```
...
/mypoint   /etc/auto.nfs
```

**auto.nfs**

```
myfiles   -fstype=nfs4   192.168.1.100:/volume2/Files
```

The result will be that your files will be under `/mypoint/myfiles`